# Solving forth order differential equation with non constant coefficients

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following differential equation nummerically, but I only seem to find the trivial solution $f(x)=0$.

How would it be possible to find a different solution to this problem?

```
G[r_] = Sin[(r*Pi)/2]
NDSolve[
  {f''''[r] + G[r]^2 f[r] == 0, f[0] == 0, f'[0] == 0, f[1] == 0, f'[1] == 0}, 
  f, {r, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE. Are you sure you are posting on the right site? There is nothing in your question making it clear that it is concerned with Mathematica software.

Comment: If you are using Mathematica, you should express your work in Wolfram Language notation.

Comment: I have edited the question and hope it is more clear now.

Comment: f=0 seems very convincingly the only solution. You've got four boundary conditions.

Comment: If a linear ODE has solution, it has only one solution or infinite many solution. 

Your equation seems to belong to the former case, try `G[r_] = Sin[(r*Pi)/2];
psol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{f''''[r] + G[r]^2 f[r] == 0, f[0] == 0, f'[0] == 0, 
   f''[0] == p2, f'''[0] == p3}, f, {r, 0, 1}, {p2, p3}]; With[{k = 10^5}, 
 ContourPlot[{psol[p2, p3][1] == 0, psol[p2, p3]'[1] == 0}, {p2, -k, k}, {p3, -k, k}]]`, but I don't know how to prove the conclusion strictly.

Comment: @xzczd and OP: please see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/125861/423150), I believe this is sufficient proof that the problem has only the trivial solution.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP I don't think so, notice [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125702/the-number-of-solutions-to-an-nth-order-differential-equation/125861#comment2888286_125861), I think it essentially states the same doubt as mine. (BTW, here is a simpler BVP of linear equation with infinite many solutions: `DSolve[{x''[t] + 4 Pi^2 x[t] == 0, x[0] == 0, x[1] == 0}, x[t], t]`. )

Comment: @xzczd This came to my mind, but I dismissed this because of the form of `G[r]`. There *could* be a singular solution, but since `G` has a period of `4`, I suspect that `r == 1` is *probably* not a singular point.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work for me. A tidier version is

```
ClearAll[G, f];
G[r_] := Sin[(r*Pi)/2];
sol = NDSolve[{f''''[r] + G[r]^2 f[r] == 0, f[0] == 0, f'[0] == 0, 
   f[1] == 0, f'[1] == 0}, f, {r, 0, 1}]
```

Where I have cleared the variables and used  := and ; (look them up).
Then to plot the result I did

```
Plot[Evaluate[f[r] /. First@sol], {r, 0, 1}]
```

and to check the error I did

```
Plot[Evaluate[f''''[r] + G[r]^2 f[r] /. First@sol], {r, 0, 1}]
```

I would have shown you the plots but my uploader has stopped working.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering my question. Unfortunately I still only find the trivial solution of approximately  $f=0$, when I used your code. If I plot the interpolatingfunction determined by the NDSolve function the values are around $10^{-25}$, while the error has peaks around $10^{-22}$. This means that the error is of three orders bigger than the function itself. Did you find the same result or did you get something else?

Comment: I got the same answer; the trivial solution, so not much use. I may delete my answer.

Comment: Nope, Hugh, your answer is absolutely correct, though very cheeky :-) I thought you were slightly pulling OP's leg (really liked the bit about the uploader).

Answer (score 1):

Following the discussion in the comments, I found it trivial to check that in all likelihood the only solution here is the trivial one.

First I dropped the `f'[1] == 0` condition and replaced it with an arbitrary condition like `f[1/2] == a`. It was easy to check with a `ParametricNDSolve` that `f` is then proportional to `a`.

```
G[r_] := Sin[(r*Pi)/2];
sol = NDSolve[{f''''[r] + G[r]^2 f[r] == 0, f[0] == 0, f'[0] == 0, 
    f[1] == 0, f[1/2] == 1}, f, {r, 0, 1}] // First
```

By doing

```
Plot[f'[r] /. sol, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

We see that the derivative of `f` is most certainly not zero at `r == 1`. Since this a linear ODE, we can conclude that if we choose to replace the boundary condition `f[1/2] == 1` with OP's desired `f'[1] == a`, we should find that `f` is again proportional to `a`. Therefore, for OP's `f'[1] == 0` we find that `f[r] === 0`.